# Page scrolling to every hash mark on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP page that loads external content using other PHP files. I'm using include so it should be pretty simple. I had a scrollTo function (below) that I removed. However, ever since I did that when I reload the main page I can see in the URL that it is scrolling to every hash mark really quick, ending in the last section.

I really don't know what script may be causing that. I used Chrome Elements but I don't see anything.

I've been trying to figure this out for the past two hours so I really need another set of eyes to help me figure out where is this coming from. So please just take a quick look.

Here is the live test page that's going crazy now.

[Test page](http://period3designs.com/tmss/l1/terminals/4100.php)

Here is the JS code I had originally, and then removed

```
$().ready(function(){

    var currentAnchor1 = null;
    //Check if it has changes
    if(currentAnchor1 != document.location.hash){
        currentAnchor1 = document.location.hash;
        //if there is not anchor, the loads the default section
        if(!currentAnchor1){
            query1 = "page=1";
        }
        else
        {
            //Creates the  string callback. This converts the url URL/#main&id=2 in URL/?section=main&id=2
            var splits1 = currentAnchor1.substring(1).split('&');
            //Get the section
            var page1 = splits1[0];
            delete splits1[0];
            var query1 = "page=" + page1;       
        }

        //Send the petition 
        $.scrollTo( document.location.hash, 500, { easing:'elasout' });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is coming from your PHP page. 4100.php is outputting inline JavaScript.

**You can't use `<!--` for block comments in JavaScript** so your `window.location` calls are indeed still happening. (For multiline comments in JavaScript, surround the lines with `/*` and `*/` instead.)

Line 2485:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.period3designs.com/tmss/l1/terminals/4100.php#4100errors"
//-->
</script>
```

Line 4779:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.period3designs.com/tmss/l1/terminals/4100.php#4100guides"
//-->
```

Line 5319:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.period3designs.com/tmss/l1/terminals/4100.php#4100howto"
//-->
</script>
```

Line 5393:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.period3designs.com/tmss/l1/terminals/4100.php#4100functions"
//-->
</script>
```

Line 5467:

```
                        <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.period3designs.com/tmss/l1/terminals/4100.php#4100menus"
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: I thought that may have cause it but I wasn't sure. What do you use to debug PHP?

Comment: I found this using Google Chrome's Developer Tools panel. Press `F12`, then go to the Scripts tab. On the left side, you'll see `www.period3designs.com`, then `tmss/l1/terminals`, then `4100.php`. Normally this will list just `.js` files, but here you'll see `4100.php` listed once for every inline `<script>` block that your PHP file outputs.

Comment: Yea all of these are coming from external pages that if visited directly (for example, from the search results page) should go to the main page. Any idea of a way around that? using PHP's header function wont work in my case...may be iframe...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're looking for or the setup here, but perhaps this will help. If page-a.php is printing the inline `<script>`, and page-a.php is one of your page that is being included in page-b.php, you can set some variable in page-b.php and then check for it in page-a.php. If the variable is not present (meaning: file was accessed directly), output the `<script>`. Otherwise (meaning: file was included by page-b.php), skip that.

Comment: Hopefully you're still here...I did this `if (!thisIsMainPage){
window.location = "http://www.period3designs.com/tmss/l1/terminals/4100.php#4100howto";
}
else{
alert (thisIsMainPage);
}` and it's working successfully on the main page(page-b.php)but not on the external pages(page-a.php), meaning it doesn't redirect....